# Inconsistent Run-time error 1004: The PivotTable field name is not valid

Tags: excel, vba

My code is my attempt at opening a workbook, then create a pivot table based on a data range on a tab titled "data".

```vb
Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTBookY As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set UKBook = _
  Workbooks.Open _
  ("File Path")

Worksheets("Data").Visible = True

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "B22"

Set PSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("B22")
Set DSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

'Define Data Range
lastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, LastCol)

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address)

'Insert Blank Pivot Table
Set PTBookY = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="PTBookY")
```

I have additional code past this to enter rows/columns/values for the pivot table, but don't believe it is relevant.

I inconsistently receive

> Run-time error 1004: The PivotTable field name is not valid"

when inserting the blank pivot table.

I noticed the code will go through more consistently if I have the workbook open and am on the Data tab.

The data range has a header in every column, and the file path and sheet names are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't rely on `ActiveWorkbook`. If you're working with the `UKBook`, then specify that. Change:

```
Worksheets("Data").Visible = True

Sheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "B22"

Set PSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("B22")
Set DSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

...

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address)
```

to

```
UKBook.Worksheets("Data").Visible = True

Set PSheet = UKBook.Sheets.Add()
PSheet.Name = "B22"
Set DSheet = UKBook.Worksheets("Data")

...

'Define Pivot Cache
Set PCache = UKBook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange.Address)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I have made the changes, but I still receiving the error.

It currently gets to creating the sheet named "B22", then stops and throws out the error.

Comment: What line throws the error?

Comment: Set PTBookY = PSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PCache, TableDestination:=PSheet.Range("A1"), TableName:="PTBookY")

Comment: https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottableerrors.html#:~:text=The%20pivot%20table%20error%2C%20%22field,heading%20value%20for%20each%20column. Otherwise out of ideas. What happens when you create the pivot table manually?

Comment: Gone through their suggestions but still no luck, stuck at the same step. Creating the Pivot table manually works without issue.

Comment: Try using the R1C1 form of the address, as well as prepending the sheet name, when using `SourceData:=PRange.Address`.